# How do I get dust particles out from between the layers of my polarizer filter for my camera

Tags: filters

I have an expensive Hoya anti-static polarizer filter.  There is dust/spots between the two pieces of lens.  How do I get them out???

Comment: Why would you want/need to remove dust from between the two plates? It will have little to no effect on image quality, even when very narrow apertures are used.

Comment: I wonder if I will ever see convex/concave polarizer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first make sure you really need to get the dust off... Dust on the filter probably isn't going to be visible on your images even at the smallest apertures, unless you're using a superwide angle lens or a fisheye (unlikely).

Having said that, and with the understanding that there's a good chance you'll destroy the filter trying to save it, this is what you can do...

The outermost filter is held in place with a retaining ring that has two small notches on opposite sides of the ring. You will need to unscrew that ring. I've been able to use my fingernails, one on each side, to unscrew these sorts of retaining rings.

Take out the front polarizer plate and gently blow out any dust between the filters. Liquid cleaners may destroy the filter material. When you've gotten as much crud out as you can, reverse the disassembly process.

One warning- with circular polarizers the front plate must go back facing the same way it came out. If you reverse the plate (put what was the outside on the inside) it will not work.

Again, you probably won't see any difference in your images- the front filter is simply too close to have any effect, even at high f-stops.

Comment: obligatory Roger Cicala blog posts: [large "dust" on front element vs. rear element](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust); [front element "issues" and relative lack of effect on picture quality](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches); [spider & web in the lens](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2014/09/the-itsy-bitsy-spider).

Comment: Yep... I tried to make that clear. If he's gotten 'wet stuff' between the plates there may be contrast and/or flare issues (much more so than dust)... But 'wet stuff' may not be clean-upable.

Answer (score 0):

Lens cleaning tools are a blower, a microfiber cloth, and lens cleaning fluid. Try to blow up dust off the lens with the blower or canned air. Finger prints can be detached with a circular wipe of the micro fiber cloth.

Comment: That's fine generic lens cleaning advice, but it does not answer the OP's question at all, which is how to get dust particles out from *between the elements of a circular polarizer?*